# Unexpected result of using the modulo operation with math.pow()

Tags: python

I'm getting the wrong answer for this:

```
long(math.factorial(100)) % long(math.pow(12, 48))
```

The answer should be 0, but Python gives:

```
3533293188234793495632656292699172292923858530336768L
```

- Why does this happen?
- How do I calculate that correctly?

Comment: Could you clarify why expected result is 0?

Comment: Why did you change the tag back from [tag:python2.x] to [tag:python]? This question is ***only*** applicable to Python 2.x. Python 3 has no notion of `long`; all numbers are implicitly converted to Long when they overflow `size_t`. There is no `long` builtin or keyword in Python 3, and `20L` is not a number literal in Python 3. This question couldn't be *more* specific to Python 2.

Comment: @ArturPadalianchyk factorial of 100 will have 48 twelves. Basically you have to count  the total number of 3s as it will limit the number of 12s (12 = 3*4 and there will be enough 4s) . While doing the counting, all multiples of 3 will have one 3, all multiples of 9 will have two three , all multiples of 27 will have three 3 and all multiples of 81 will have one three. So we get the count as 33 + 11 + 3 + 1 = 48. (100 has 33 threes, 11 nines, 3 twenty sevens and 1 eighty one)

Comment: @tac because even if you remove "long" and have it implicitly converted in Python 3, the same "problem" is still there. The answer given by Martjin is relevant to Python 2 and 3.

Comment: @ArturPadalianchyk Because it is...? That's a strange question.

Comment: @tac: the same problem would apply if you used `int()`, in either Python 2 or Python 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are making assumptions about floating point conversions that don't hold. A floating point number is an *approximation*, using binary fractions, with a limited precision.

You are creating a very large number here:

```
>>> math.pow(12, 48)
6.319748715279271e+51
```

That's a 52 digit figure, but a floating point number can't precisely model all those digits. Converting that number to an integer is going to result in an imprecise result:

```
>>> long(math.pow(12, 48)) - (12 ** 48)
351985927636009487190448992086392832L
```

That's 36 digits of imprecision.

The answer is to *not* use `math.pow()`; use the `**` exponent operator on integers:

```
>>> math.factorial(100) % (12 ** 48)
0L
```